Instagram Graph Api Access Token confuesd
im making an app using Instagram Graph Api , so i get user instagram posts and stuff
but im bit confused is the only way to get posts is with the user access token ? like what if want to show the posts to other people and let people comment for example , everytime i want to show user posts for another users i want to get the posts from user access token? it just seems illegal , anyone could help me with that
